# Jquery mobile filterable select ignorar acentuação

Tags: select, jquery-mobile, dropdown

Boas,

Estou a experimentar uma select box retirada deste exemplo http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom-filter/ funciona perfeitamente mas ao tentar filtrar os resultados escrevendo por exemplo Águeda o resultado é nulo apenas aceitando Agueda, será que alguém me pode ajudar a converter a  busca de forma a ignorar os acentos?

Obrigado.

Comment: Talvez [esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11772241/1398670) lhe ajude

Comment: Obrigado já está a funcionar!